# JQuery selector table inside table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

hi here is the xpath of an element which i wanted to select with the jquery but couldn't do, 
for the very first occurrence only.
please help me.
XPATH ::

"/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table table");
```

Or more specific:

```
$("table > tbody > tr > td:th-child(2) > table");
```

But an ID would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to give the table an ID to select instead, but otherwise something like the following mess should work.

```
$table = $("html body table tbody tr td:eq(2) table").first();
```